# Access Denied: Connecting to RDS using IAM Role

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

After several hours, I have given up and am seeking help from the community.

1. I have a RDS Aurora MySQL instance
2. I have an IAM Policy defined that allows `rds-db` connections for a particular database user - `jane_doe`
3. I have created a user `jane_doe` directly on the MySQL database with `AuthenticationType` as `AWSAuthenticationPlugin`
4. I have enabled SSL required for `jane_doe` and have downloaded the required certs from AWS
5. I am able to connect to the DB from my local terminal by providing admin username and password

***THIS WORKS***

```
mysql --host=db-test-instance-1.somethinghere.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306 --ssl-ca=~/Downloads/global-bundle.pem --enable-cleartext-plugin --user=admin --password=my_password
```

6. However if I try to connect using an Auth Token and user jane_doe, I get an access denied error

***THIS DOES NOT WORK***

```
TOKEN="$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname db-test-instance-1.somethinghere.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port 3306 --username jane_doe --region=us-west-2b)"

mysql --host=db-test-instance-1.something here.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306 --ssl-ca=~/Downloads/global-bundle.pem --enable-cleartext-plugin --user=jane_doe --password=$TOKEN

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jane_doe'@'1.16.14.7' (using password: YES)
```

7. I have verified that `jane_doe` exists on the database and has the required grants.

I am stumped... thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: That 'close vote' was recorded as a recommendation that the question instead be submitted at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you may need to flush privileges - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html#flush-privileges

Also see some of the answers here - [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)